# Missing eav attribute options in collection

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, eav-attributes

I miss some custom attribute options in my collection.
I'm using the standard `"\Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Grouped::getAssociatedProducts"` method.
When I debug the collection inside that method there are not all attributes listed.
By adding load to an item everything is there but I don't need all 124 elements inside only some of them.

```
foreach ($collection as $item) {
    $item->load($item->getId());
    $associatedProducts[] = $item;
}
```

As for performance that load method is definitly an overkill but I can't find the problem why it isn't there.
In the database table `"eav_attribute_option"` I can see every needed attribute but not in the Select-Statement.
I don't it for the product list only on the product detail page. So I haven't tried to enable the option `"used in product listing"`.